# What would be the correct way to to this to counter multiple xpath selectors?

Tags: python, mysql, for-loop, xpath, scrapy

Very tired sleeping only 3 hrs and being awake for 20+ hrs, forgive my mistakes.

I am trying to achieve multiple xpath selectors but cant seem to get it, clearly this code has a flaw code, repeating description and it ends up taking the last item's description and alocate it to all items, screenshots and code:

shows what i am meaning to saw in a visual representation:
[this http://puu.sh/fBjA9/da85290fc2.png](http://puu.sh/fBjA9/da85290fc2.png)

Code(Scrapy Web Crawler Python):
Spider

```
 def parse(self, response):
     item = DmozItem()
     for sel in response.xpath("//td[@class='nblu tabcontent']"):
         item['title'] = sel.xpath("a/big/text()").extract()
         item['link'] = sel.xpath("a/@href").extract()
         for sel in response.xpath("//td[contains(@class,'framed')]"):
             item['description'] = sel.xpath("b/text()").extract()    
         yield item
```

Pipeline

```
 def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM data WHERE title= %s", item['title'])
        result = self.cursor.fetchall()
        if result:

            log.msg("Item already in database: %s" % item, level=log.DEBUG)
        else:
            self.cursor.execute(
               "INSERT INTO data(title, url, description) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)",
                    (item['title'][0], item['link'][0], item['description'][0]))
            self.connection.commit()

            log.msg("Item stored : " % item, level=log.DEBUG)
        return item

    def handle_error(self, e):
            log.err(e)
```

Thank You for reading and offering help.

Comment: The scrapy code doesn't mean much without seeing the html; got a url?

Comment: @HughBothwell here it is, thanks. http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/class/130.html

Comment: @HughBothwell Going to sleep, will be up in 6 hrs prolly. Nearing 24 hrs without sleep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `"//td[@class='nblu tabcontent']"` and `"//td[contains(@class,'framed')]"` are in one-to-one correspondence; you cannot iterate one inside the other or, as you are finding, you only get the last item from the inner list.

Instead, try

```
def parse(self, response):
    title_links  = response.xpath("//td[@class='nblu tabcontent']")
    descriptions = response.xpath("//td[contains(@class,'framed')]")
    for tl,d in zip(title_links, descriptions):
        item = DmozItem()
        item['title']       = tl.xpath("a/big/text()").extract()
        item['link']        = tl.xpath("a/@href").extract()
        item['description'] = d.xpath("b/text()").extract()    
        yield item
```

Comment: Oh my, thanks, did work. I guess it would be just wrong placement of loops. Help Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you simply need to move the item instantiation inside the for loop:

```
def parse(self, response):
   for sel in response.xpath("//td[@class='nblu tabcontent']"):
       item = DmozItem()
       item['title'] = sel.xpath("a/big/text()").extract()
       item['link'] = sel.xpath("a/@href").extract()
       for sel in response.xpath("//td[contains(@class,'framed')]"):
         item['description'] = sel.xpath("b/text()").extract()    
     yield item
```

Comment: Hmm, still no effect.

Comment: tried using //html as the master response.xpath
Code:http://hastebin.com/tinaduwezu.coffee
Screenshot(got this): http://puu.sh/fCyVD/6707bc2d82.png
but would result in a mysql error - ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement